# Table like data structure in Java

Tags: java

Forgive me if this question has been answered elsewhere, but I have searched long and hard and have not found an answer.

I am new to Java programming and I wish to create a simple table like data structure, that I can manipulate as required.

For example:

Name,Age,Hair_Colour
Bob,20,Black
John,25,Brown
Larry,30,Black

In powershell, I would just create a custom object, populate it and them append to an array.  However, I'm struggling with coding it in Java.

I would appreciate any help that anyone can provide me with.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very basic question and it is hardly a place to ask this... I recommend you to start your Java experience with a good beginners book. I think that Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" is a good start.

As for the question itself - try with ArrayList. It is backened by a regular table, but has a very handy interface. A few examples:

```
// a handy way to create a prepopulated list
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");

// creating an empty ArrayList
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// adding an element
list.add("a string");
// adding a whole collection
list.addAll(listOfStrings);
```

Java is a strongly typed language, so if you need a bean holding name, age and hair colour you need to create a class for this. Let's say this is a Person class:

```
package my_package;

public class Person {
private String name;
private String hairColour;
private int age;

public Person(String name, String hairColour, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hairColour = hairColour;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getHairColour() {
    return hairColour;
}
public void setHairColour(String hairColour) {
    this.hairColour = hairColour;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

You need to create objects of this type and insert those into the ArrayList like before:

```
List<Person> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
listOfPeople.add(new Person("Bob", "Brown", 39));
```

Comment: Hi theadam.  Thanks for your reply.  I appreciate that I probably need to do some reading before I start posting questions here.  Having looked through your example, it makes a lot of sense.  I have a play with this and hopefully get the result that I am after.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you considered this question answered, then feel free to choose the answer by clicking the grey tick. If not then let me know what else would you expect from an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a table and perform arbitrary queries like SUM, GROUP BY etc. then you'll best go with in memory databases like H2. Otherwise you can define a custom object (i.e. a class) and append it to a collection.